# Blender's inset is extending outwards

Tags: modeling, faces

I'm following a tutorial for a base mesh, and I kind of went off and defined the head myself. I added two extra line things (Ctrl+R) just to shape the head the way I wanted,

but when I tried to resume the tutorial and add an inset for the eye, the inset was expanding past the selected faces instead of going inwards like it's supposed to.

**Before Inset:**

[image: 1]

**How it's supposed to look:**

[image: 2]

**What inset is doing for me:**

[image: 3]

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn off *Proportional Edit* by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> key.

I was messing with the <kbd>O</kbd> key earlier for to soft push around the faces, so I must've accidently pressed that while insetting and made it an offset.